# Not converting all characters in Norwegian language

Tags: php, magento

I have the following lines in English :

> By creating an account with our store, you will be able to move
>   through the checkout process faster, store multiple shipping
>   addresses, view and track your orders in your account and more.

I translated these to Norwegian:

> Ved � opprette en konto hos oss vil du enklere kunne gjennomf�re
>   fremtidige kj�p, f� oversikt over alle dine kj�p, osv.

But I am getting questionmarks (`?`) within the words. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to encode/decode special chars (html entity) in your code.

Comment: I am using <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"> . But its happening in all website

Comment: Do you get those Text from db?

Comment: no i am getting it from here loing.phtm file <?php echo $this->__('By creating an account with our store, you will be able to move through the checkout process faster, store multiple shipping addresses, view and track your orders in your account and more.') ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The translation csv sounds like it has the wrong encoding.  It should be re-encoded to UTF-8.

The file in question is;

```
 app/locale/nb_NO/Mage_Customer.csv
```

You can re-encode it with various programmes, my preference is for open office calc, which is free, but i'm sure you can find the solution.

By the way, if you downloaded the language pack from the Magento Connect centre, looking at the reviews it looks as though a few of the files arent encoded correctly http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magento-community-modules-norwegian-bokmal-norway-language-pack.html

Comment: i got the following for this file Mage_customer.csv "By creating an account with our store, you will be able to move through the checkout process faster, store multiple shipping addresses, view and track your orders in your account and more.","Ved å opprette en konto hos oss vil du enklere kunne gjennomføre fremtidige kjøp, få oversikt over alle dine kjøp, osv."

Comment: Hi, what are you reading the file with?  If you are opening in excel, excel adjusts the encoding to present you the information.  That's why i use openoffice ;)

Comment: I didnt do anything i just created multistore in magento.

Comment: I'd be happy to take a look at the file for you if you like - send it to me tom@pixiemedia.co.uk atleast then we can rule the encoding issue out

Comment: i am using magento 1.9.0.1